# How to define own routing helpers in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I use polimorphic_path and it some buggy. This method require some route helper that not defined. How can I define (like regular method) own route helper which will be used like "model_name_path, model_name_url etc"?

Answer (score 4):

This solution worked for me.

Add this code to the end of `config/routes.rb` file. Make sure to replace `MyApp` with your application's name.

```
MyApp::Application.routes.named_routes.module.module_eval do
  def model_name_path(*args)
    # Your code here
  end

  def model_name_url(*args)
    # Your code here
  end
end

MyApp::Application.routes.named_routes.instance_eval do
  @helpers += [:model_name_path, :model_name_url]
end
```

These custom methods will be available in controllers, views and tests.

Comment: in Rails 4:  Rails.application.routes.named_routes.url_helpers_module.module_eval do ...

Answer (score 2):

I know one possible answer for _path, but the same isn't working for me for _url. Anybody know why?

```
# at the bottom of config/routes.rb
module ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper
    def model_name_path model, args={}
        # your implementation
    end
end
```

Comment: Oh, I think it does work for _url too, just that I was calling the _url from a controller and not a view.

Comment: Say I have a helper method name called user_links, where do I specify the method name as per your e.g., . I have a Post model. My code, looks like this:- ~ module ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper
    def post_name_path post, args={}
        # your implementation --> what exactly should this have ?
    end 
end ~

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried using an appropriate code block but somehow couldn't get it right in the comments section.